# Babel generating 6.4GB size logs while doing prod build ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, babeljs

I am just migrating one of the ionic project with angular 9 to angular 10 everything works fine but while generating the prod build babel logs are going into the loop and generating 6.4 GB worth logs.
I have tried multiple babel configurations but the result is the same. How can I reduce the logs?

`ng build --prod` is generating the following logs

Sample repo link

https://github.com/vpPavithra/SunbirdEd-mobile-app/commits/release-5.1.2_v10

Sample log

```
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.directives[0] Directive: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.directives[0] Directive: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.directives[0].value DirectiveLiteral: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.directives[0].value DirectiveLiteral: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.directives[0].value DirectiveLiteral: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.directives[0] Directive: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.body[0] ExpressionStatement: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.965Z babel program.body[0] ExpressionStatement: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.966Z babel program.body[0].expression AssignmentExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.966Z babel program.body[0].expression AssignmentExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.966Z babel program.body[0].expression.left MemberExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.966Z babel program.body[0].expression.left MemberExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.966Z babel program.body[0].expression.left.object Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.967Z babel program.body[0].expression.left.object Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.967Z babel program.body[0].expression.left.object Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.967Z babel program.body[0].expression.left.property Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.967Z babel program.body[0].expression.left.property Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.967Z babel program.body[0].expression.left.property Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.967Z babel program.body[0].expression.left MemberExpression: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.967Z babel program.body[0].expression.right FunctionExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right FunctionExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.params[0] Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.params[0] Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.params[0] Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body BlockStatement: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body BlockStatement: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0] VariableDeclaration: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0] VariableDeclaration: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0] VariableDeclarator: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0] VariableDeclarator: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0].id Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0].id Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0].id Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0].init ArrayExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0].init ArrayExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.968Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0].init ArrayExpression: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0].declarations[0] VariableDeclarator: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[0] VariableDeclaration: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1] ExpressionStatement: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1] ExpressionStatement: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression AssignmentExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression AssignmentExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left MemberExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left MemberExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left.object Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left.object Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left.object Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left.property Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left.property Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left.property Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.left MemberExpression: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right FunctionExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right FunctionExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.id Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.id Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.id Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body BlockStatement: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body BlockStatement: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0] ReturnStatement: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0] ReturnStatement: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument CallExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument CallExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee MemberExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee MemberExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object CallExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object CallExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee MemberExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee MemberExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee.object ThisExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.969Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee.object ThisExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee.object ThisExpression: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee.property Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee.property Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee.property Identifier: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.callee MemberExpression: exit
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.arguments[0] FunctionExpression: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.arguments[0] FunctionExpression: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.arguments[0].params[0] Identifier: enter
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.arguments[0].params[0] Identifier: Recursing into...
2023-03-17T16:06:58.970Z babel program.body[0].expression.right.body.body[1].expression.right.body.body[0].argument.callee.object.arguments[0].params[0] Identifier: exit
```

How to reduce the babel logs ?

Comment: Where do you have Babel from? Angular and Ionic don't use Babel as per my memory. Especially Angular

Answer (score 0):

Update the babel.config.js file to include the following configuration:

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        [
          "transform-remove-console",
          {
            "exclude": ["error", "warn"]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This configuration removes all console logs except for error and warn messages. This will significantly reduce the amount of logs generated by Babel during the production build.

Comment: will it remove console log from my code or it will remove from the ng build command as my issue is ng build --prod is generating all these logs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the babel logs are going into a loop, causing the build to generate a large amount of logs.

You can use the minimal preset: You can use the @babel/preset-env preset with the minimal option to reduce the amount of logging that babel produces. If you chose this way, your `babel.config.js` became as follow:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 11'],
        },
        debug: false,
        modules: false,
        loose: true,
        corejs: 3,
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
        shippedProposals: true,
        minimal: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: @Bennny Still generating same amount of logs.

Comment: Is it possible that these logs are coming from a third party library that you have installed in your project? Try to analyze you project with `webpack-bundle-analyzer`. This may give you some insights into which dependencies are contributing to the large amount of logs being generated.

Comment: webpack-bundle-analyzer will analyze the bundle how it will verify the build logs.